# How do I prevent Firefox from adding vertical scrollbars to a select dropdown when changing the background color?

Tags: html, css, firefox, forms

I'm trying to change the background color of a select dropdown. This works in Chrome, Safari & Firefox. However, when changing the background color of the select element in Firefox to anything other than `#FFFFFF`, the dropdown appearance changes. It looks like Firefox is no longer using the default macOS UI for the dropdown: the rounded corners are gone, scrollbars appear, and the font size, spacing & smoothing are different.

I've tried tinkering with `-moz-appearance: none;` or targeting the option elements, but neither solves the problem.

Example of #FFFFFF select background in Firefox:
[image: Example of #FFFFFF select background in Firefox]

Example of any other color select background in Firefox:
[image: Background color dropdown issue in Firefox]

Background color dropdown works correctly in Chrome & Safari:
[image: Correct dropdown in Chrome]

Codepen comparing the different results: https://codepen.io/ian-pvd/pen/XxdKJB

(View it in Firefox, and compare the results with other browsers.)

Is there a style or hack which prevents this, or forces the select dropdown to use the system UI?

Firefox: 62.0.2
Chrome: 69.0.3497.100
Safari: 11.0.3
OS: macOS 10.13.3

Answer (score 1):

Is there a style or hack which prevents this, or forces the select dropdown to use the system UI?

Yes [**jquery-nice-select**](https://hernansartorio.com/jquery-nice-select/)

Comment: Thanks but, I'm trying to force the native dropdown UI with CSS, and this is a "jQuery plugin that replaces native select elements with customizable dropdowns" which is the opposite of what I want to do.